# Unable to start RestHeart Security

Tags: restheart

I am unable to start Restheart Security. Anyone knows what might be wrong? I am in the dark. I get the following error

```
[main] [1;31mERROR[0;39m org.restheart.security.Bootstrapper - Error starting RESTHeart Security. Exiting...
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error configuring Authentication Mechanism basicAuthMechanism
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
    at org.restheart.security.cache.impl.GuavaLoadingCache.getLoading(GuavaLoadingCache.java:63)
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.PluginsRegistry.getAuthenticationMechanism(PluginsRegistry.java:320)
    at org.restheart.security.Bootstrapper.lambda$authMechanisms$7(Bootstrapper.java:760)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:502)
    at org.restheart.security.Bootstrapper.authMechanisms(Bootstrapper.java:756)
    at org.restheart.security.Bootstrapper.startCoreSystem(Bootstrapper.java:615)
    at org.restheart.security.Bootstrapper.startServer(Bootstrapper.java:478)
    at org.restheart.security.Bootstrapper.run(Bootstrapper.java:220)
    at org.restheart.security.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:188)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error configuring Authentication Mechanism basicAuthMechanism
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.PluginsRegistry.lambda$static$3(PluginsRegistry.java:103)
    at org.restheart.security.cache.impl.GuavaLoadingCache$1.load(GuavaLoadingCache.java:51)
    at org.restheart.security.cache.impl.GuavaLoadingCache$1.load(GuavaLoadingCache.java:48)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.restheart.security.ConfigurationException: Error configuring Authentication Mechanism basicAuthMechanism
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.PluginsFactory.createAutenticationMechanism(PluginsFactory.java:99)
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.PluginsRegistry.lambda$static$3(PluginsRegistry.java:100)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.PluginsFactory.createAutenticationMechanism(PluginsFactory.java:87)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error configuring Authenticator simpleFileAuthenticator
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
    at org.restheart.security.cache.impl.GuavaLoadingCache.getLoading(GuavaLoadingCache.java:63)
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.PluginsRegistry.getAuthenticator(PluginsRegistry.java:302)
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.mechanisms.BasicAuthMechanism.<init>(BasicAuthMechanism.java:46)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error configuring Authenticator simpleFileAuthenticator
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.PluginsRegistry.lambda$static$1(PluginsRegistry.java:75)
    at org.restheart.security.cache.impl.GuavaLoadingCache$1.load(GuavaLoadingCache.java:51)
    at org.restheart.security.cache.impl.GuavaLoadingCache$1.load(GuavaLoadingCache.java:48)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.restheart.security.ConfigurationException: Error configuring Authenticator simpleFileAuthenticator
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.PluginsFactory.createAuthenticator(PluginsFactory.java:168)
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.PluginsRegistry.lambda$static$1(PluginsRegistry.java:72)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.PluginsFactory.createAuthenticator(PluginsFactory.java:156)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:218)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.ensureEnoughData(StreamReader.java:176)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.ensureEnoughData(StreamReader.java:171)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.peek(StreamReader.java:126)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanToNextToken(ScannerImpl.java:1177)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:287)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:227)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseImplicitDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:195)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:148)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:107)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:139)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:524)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:452)
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.FileConfigurablePlugin.init(FileConfigurablePlugin.java:65)
    at org.restheart.security.plugins.authenticators.SimpleFileAuthenticator.<init>(SimpleFileAuthenticator.java:65)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:274)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.read(UnicodeReader.java:125)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:183)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
16:56:46.445 [main] [34mINFO [0;39m org.restheart.security.Bootstrapper - Stopping RESTHeart Security...
16:56:46.446 [main] [34mINFO [0;39m org.restheart.security.Bootstrapper - Cleaning up temporary directories...
16:56:46.448 [main] [34mINFO [0;39m org.restheart.security.Bootstrapper - [32;1mRESTHeart Security stopped[m
```

The start command is

```
"D:\apps\MongoDB\jdk-11.0.5_windows-x64_bin\jdk-11.0.5\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=.\etc\rhTrustStore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=hidden -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -jar restheart-security.jar .\etc\restheart-security.yml -e .\etc\default.properties
```

the relevant block in my main config file is

```
auth-mechanisms:
 #   - name: tokenBasicAuthMechanism
 #     class: org.restheart.security.plugins.mechanisms.TokenBasicAuthMechanism
 #     args:
 #       realm: RESTHeart Realm
    - name: basicAuthMechanism
      class:  org.restheart.security.plugins.mechanisms.BasicAuthMechanism
      args:
        realm: RESTHeart Realm
        authenticator: simpleFileAuthenticator
  #  - name: digestAuthMechanism
  #    class:  org.restheart.security.plugins.mechanisms.DigestAuthMechanism
  #    args:
  #      realm: RESTHeart Realm
  #      domain: localhost
  #      authenticator: simpleFileAuthenticator
#    - name: identityAuthenticationMechanism
#      class: org.restheart.security.plugins.mechanisms.IdentityAuthMechanism
#      args:
#        username: admin
#        roles:
#            - admin
#            - user

## Authenticators

 # An Authenticator verify user credential and are used by one or more
 # AuthMachanisms

 # See README.md for the list of available Authenticators

authenticators:
    - name: simpleFileAuthenticator
      class: org.restheart.security.plugins.authenticators.SimpleFileAuthenticator
      args:
        conf-file: .\etc\users.yml

## Authorizers

 # Authorizers verify if a request is allowed.

 # As an in-bound request is received and authenticated the isAllowed() method is
 # called on each authenticator in turn until one of the following occurs:
 # an authenticator allows the incoming request or the list of authenticators is
 # exhausted. In the latter case, the request ends and 403 Forbidden is returned.

 # See README.md for the list of available Authorizers

authorizers:
    - name: requestPredicatesAuthorizer
      class: org.restheart.security.plugins.authorizers.RequestPredicatesAuthorizer
      args:
        conf-file: .\etc\acl.yml
```

And the users and acl files are

### configuration file for simpleFileAuthenticator

```
users:      
   - userid: hidden
    password: hidden
    roles: [users]

  - userid: hidden
    password: hidden
    roles: [users]

## configuration file for requestPredicatesAuthorizer
permissions:
    # OPTIONS is always allowed

    - role: $unauthenticated
      predicate: path-prefix[path="/echo"] and method[value="GET"]

    - role: admin
      predicate: path-prefix[path="/"]

  # Users with role 'users' can GET any collection or document resource (excluding dbs and _logic )
  - role: users
    predicate: regex[pattern="/.*/.*", value="%R", full-match=true] and method[value="GET"] and not path-prefix[path="/_logic"]

  # Users with role 'users' can request URI /_logic/csv
  - role: users
    predicate: path["/_logic/csv"]

  # Users with role 'users' can do anything on the collection /publicdb/{username}
  - role: users
    predicate: path-template[value="/publicdb/{username}"] and equals[%u, "${username}"]

  # Users with role 'users' can do anything on documents of the collection /publicdb/{username}
  - role: users
    predicate: path-template[value="/publicdb/{username}/{doc}"] and equals[%u, "${username}"]
```

Using version 4.1.3 and I have no clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, tip of the week don't use € in your passwords :-)

Answer (score 0):

Relevant message seems to be: "Error configuring Authenticator simpleFileAuthenticator"

Your configuration file for simpleFileAuthenticator looks to have an indentation problem.

you can use an online yaml validator as https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator to check your conf file

the correct users.yml file is

```
users:      
  - userid: hidden
    password: hidden
    roles: [users]

  - userid: hidden
    password: hidden
    roles: [users]

## configuration file for requestPredicatesAuthorizer
permissions:
    # OPTIONS is always allowed

  - role: $unauthenticated
      predicate: path-prefix[path="/echo"] and method[value="GET"]

  - role: admin
      predicate: path-prefix[path="/"]

  # Users with role 'users' can GET any collection or document resource (excluding dbs and _logic )
  - role: users
    predicate: regex[pattern="/.*/.*", value="%R", full-match=true] and method[value="GET"] and not path-prefix[path="/_logic"]

  # Users with role 'users' can request URI /_logic/csv
  - role: users
    predicate: path["/_logic/csv"]

  # Users with role 'users' can do anything on the collection /publicdb/{username}
  - role: users
    predicate: path-template[value="/publicdb/{username}"] and equals[%u, "${username}"]

  # Users with role 'users' can do anything on documents of the collection /publicdb/{username}
  - role: users
    predicate: path-template[value="/publicdb/{username}/{doc}"] and equals[%u, "${username}"]
```